# publish MQTT message in Java/android

Tags: java, android, mqtt, paho

I'm using `paho.android.service` for communication with the broker and it is connecting successfully. but can't understand how can I send messages to the topic. On the other side, I have a `ESP8266` that receives the Command and turn Light on/off.

This is the function that sends message to topic:

```
public void pub(View v) {
    String topic = "/home/1/ard1/p1/com:command:on:1";
    String message = "Turn the LED ON!"
    try {
        client.publish(topic, message.getBytes(),0,false);
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This line: `String topic = "/home/1/ard1/p1/com:command:on:1";` is working fine when I'm using Openhab for communication with ESP8266.

My question is: how can I convert this code to send a command here?

Thanks.
Morteza.

Comment: You want to receive messages? In that case you have to subscribe to that topic.

Comment: @emKaroly How? i'm following this tutorial: http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-enyclopedia-paho-android-service

Comment: In that tutorial is the Subscribe section. Basically you call client.subscribe(topic) and you will receive them with callback. MQTT works like this: You got a broker you publish messages to topic and all clients subscribed to that topic will receive them.

Comment: @emKaroly now I'm able subscribe to the topic, but my ESP8266 doesn't respond.

Comment: Are you sure that your device is sending something?